# Object methods and fields co-exist in Lua library

Tags: lua

EDIT: Turns out this is not something possible with Lua, having the __index method AND methods like class instance methods. It's either or.

Trying to get my Lua interface to work where both fields and instance methods are supported. It seems that by manipulating the initialization, I can only get the functions (_f), or the methods (_m) to work, not both.

I feel like it's something really simple I'm just missing.

How I initialize the library:

```
void PushUserdata(const void *data, const char *metatable)
{
    const void **wrapped_ptr = (const void**)lua_newuserdata(l, sizeof(const void*));
    *wrapped_ptr = data;
    luaL_getmetatable(l, metatable);
    lua_setmetatable(l, -2);
}

static int player_head(lua_State *L)
{
    if (!Player::playerHead)
        lua_pushnil(L);
    else
        PushUserdata(Player::playerHead, "player");

    return 1;
}

static int playerget(lua_State *L)
{
    Player *player = *CHECKPLAYER(L, 1); // Get double pointer and dereference to get real pointer

    const char *field = luaL_checkstring(L, 2);

    if (!strcmp(field, "next"))
    {
        if (!player->next)
            lua_pushnil(L);
        else
            PushUserdata(player->next, "player");
    }
    else if (!strcmp(field, "prev"))
    {
        if (!player->prev)
            lua_pushnil(L);
        else
            PushUserdata(player->prev, "player");
    }
    else if (!strcmp(field, "obj"))
    {
        if (!player->obj)
            lua_pushnil(L);
        else
            PushUserdata(player->obj, "wobj");
    }
    else if (!strcmp(field, "AddCollisionObjHook")) // This ends up here if __index is in the table below...
    {
    }
    else
        return 0;

    return 1;
}

static const struct luaL_Reg playerlib_f[] = {
    {"head", player_head},
    {"AddPreThinker", AddPreThinker},
    {"AddPostThinker", AddPostThinker},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

static const struct luaL_Reg playerlib_m[] = {
    {"__tostring", player2string},
    {"__index", playerget},
    {"__newindex", playerset},
    {"AddCollisionObjHook", AddCollisionObjHook},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

int Lua_PlayerLib(lua_State *L)
{
    luaL_newmetatable(L, "player");
    lua_pushvalue(L, -1); // duplicates the metatable...but why?
    luaL_setfuncs(L, playerlib_m, 0);
    luaL_newlib(L, playerlib_f, 0);
    lua_setglobal(L, "player");

    return 1;
}
```

Lua script:

```
me = playerlib.head()
me:AddCollisionObjHook(playerHitObj)
```

Error message:

```
Warning: [string "postload.lua"]: attempt to call method 'AddCollisionObjHook' (a nil value)
```

'me' is absolutely a valid non-nil value.

Comment: At a glance, it looks like `player_head` is doing something wrong. Please add that function definition to the question.

Comment: Done, but the head() function correctly returns a pointer to the necessary object.

Comment: Ok, I've looked through all the code. It now looks like `playerget` is the prime suspect.

Comment: Right, the interpreter is calling playerget(), even though 'AddCollisionObjHook' is a valid metamethod. Isn't playerget() only supposed to be called if the method is not found in the list?

Comment: `me` is a userdata. Userdatas don't natively support indexing. The only way to index it is to call its metatable's `__index`. So `playerget` needs to include code to look inside the `playerlib` table.

Comment: s/`playerlib`/`player`. It won't let me edit my comment.

Comment: I just edited the code above. If I comment out
{"__index", playerget}, it works as expected and calls the AddCollisionObjHook. But then none of the fields work...

Comment: Try to assign a Lua table to userdata's mt __index field.  And playerget would be the __index field of mt of this Lua table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do *is* possible, but not in the way you're trying to do it.

I think it's worth reviewing how method calls and metatables/metamethods work, and what your code, as written, is actually doing. The tl;dr is:

- method calls are just normal field lookups
- metatables, and the metamethods they contain, are *operator overloads*, not method definitions
- if you're implementing this for userdata you need an `__index` metamethod that can handle both field and method lookups

---

First of all, Lua has no inbuilt distinction between "methods" and "fields". You may find it convenient to differentiate the two when organizing your code, but as far as the Lua language is concerned *methods and fields are the same thing*. A method is just a field where the key is a valid lua identifier and the value is a function.

So, when you write something like `me:AddCollisionObjHook(playerHitObj)`, what actually happens is something like:

```
local self = me
local method = self["AddCollisionObjHook"]
method(self, playerHitObj)
```

(Two notes on this:

- no actual new locals are created; this all happens in the internals of the Lua interpreter.
- `self["AddCollisionObjHook"]` and `self.AddCollisionObjHook` are two ways of writing the same thing; the latter is just a convenient shortcut for the former.)

So, how does that `self["AddCollisionObjHook"]` lookup work? The same way any other field lookup works. The Lua Manual goes into detail on this, including pseudocode, but the part relevant to your code is:

```
-- We're looking up self[key] but self is userdata, not table
local mt = getmetatable(self)
if mt and type(mt.__index) == 'function' then
  -- user provided an __index function
  return mt.__index(self, key)
elseif mt and mt.__index ~= nil then
  -- user provided an __index table (or table-like object)
  -- retry the lookup using it
  return mt.__index[key]
else
  -- no metatable, or metatable lacks __index metamethod
  error(...) -- don't know how to do field lookup on this type!
end
```

Note that *at no point in this process are fields other than `__index` looked up in the metatable*. The metatable exists *only* to tell Lua how to implement operators for types that don't normally have them; in this case the field lookup ("index") operator (`[]`, and its aliases `.` and `:`) for a specific kind of userdata. It's entirely down to `__index` itself to handle the actual process of turning field names into values, either by being a table that the lookup can be retried with or by being a function that can return the associated value.

So, this brings us to the answer of how to support both (settable) fields and (callable) methods:

- `__newindex` needs to understand how to set fields
- `__index` needs to understand how to return *both* field values *and* method implementations

Since, from Lua's perspective, both field lookups and method lookups are the same operation, and thus `__index` gets used for both.

---

In light of that, how should we organize the code to support both, and how can we restructure your code to work? There's lots of ways to do this, although for the purposes of this answer I'm going to make a few assumptions:

- *fields* are stored entirely C-side, with no corresponding data to manage in Lua
- *methods* cannot be overwritten by Lua code
- *metamethods* are stored separately from *instance methods*

The last one is not strictly necessary; in fact it's very common to store both metamethods and instance methods in the same table (I usually do this myself). However, I think this also tends to engender confusion among Lua newbies about the distinction between them, so the interest of making the code as clear as possible, I'm separating them out in this answer.

---

With that in mind, let's rework the setup code. I've looked at your edits to try to reconstruct what you originally had in mind.

```c
static int playerget(lua_State *L)
{
    Player *player = *CHECKPLAYER(L, 1);
    const char *field = luaL_checkstring(L, 2);

    // Check if it's a method, by getting the method table
    // and then seeing if the key exists in it.
    // This code can be re-used (or factored out into its own function)
    // at the start of playerset() to raise an error if the lua code tries
    // to overwrite a method.
    lua_getfield(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, "player-methods");
    lua_getfield(L, -1, field);
    if (!lua_isnil(L, -1)) {
      // Lookup in methods table successful, so return the method impl, which
      // is now on top of the stack
      return 1;
    } else {
      // No method, so clean up the stack of both the nil value and the
      // table of methods we got it from.
      lua_pop(L, 2);
    }


    if (!strcmp(field, "next"))
    // ... code for reading fields rather than methods goes here ... //
}

// Functions that are part of the player library rather than tied to any
// one player instance.
static const struct luaL_Reg playerlib_api[] = {
    // player.head() -> returns the first player
    {"head", player_head},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

// Metamethods defining legal operators on player-type objects.
static const struct luaL_Reg playerlib_metamethods[] = {
    // Overrides the tostring() library function
    {"__tostring", player2string},
    // Adds support for the table read operators:
    // t[k], t.k, and t:k(...)
    {"__index", playerget},
    // Adds support for the table write operators:
    // t[k]=v and t.k=v
    {"__newindex", playerset},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

// Instance methods for player-type objects.
static const struct luaL_Reg playerlib_methods[] = {
    // player_obj:AddCollisionObjHook(hook)
    {"AddCollisionObjHook", AddCollisionObjHook},
    // player_obj:AddPreThinker(thinker)
    {"AddPreThinker", AddPreThinker},
    // player_obj:AddPostThinker(thinker)
    {"AddPostThinker", AddPostThinker},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

int Lua_PlayerLib(lua_State *L)
{
    // Create the metatable and fill it with the stuff from playerlib_metamethods.
    // Every time a player object is pushed into Lua (via player_head() or similar)
    // this metatable will get attached to it, allowing lua to see the __index,
    // __newindex, and __tostring metamethods for it.
    luaL_newmetatable(L, "player");
    luaL_setfuncs(L, playerlib_metamethods, 0);
    lua_pop(L, 1);

    // Create the method table and fill it.
    // We push the key we're going to be storing it in the registry under,
    // then the table itself, then store it into the registry.
    lua_pushliteral(L, "player-methods");
    luaL_newlib(L, playerlib_methods, 0);
    lua_settable(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);

    // Initialize the `player` library with the API functions.
    luaL_newlib(L, playerlib_api, 0);
    // Set that table as the value of the global "player".
    // This also pops it, so we duplicate it first...
    lua_pushvalue(L, -1);
    lua_setglobal(L, "player");

    // ...so that we can also return it, so that constructs like
    // local player = require 'player'; work properly.
    return 1;
}
```

Breaking it down, this gives us three tables:

- `player`, which holds the actual library API like `player.head()`
- `REGISTRY["player"]`, which holds the metatable shared by all player objects

  - `__tostring` which is invoked for prettyprinting
  - `__newindex` which is invoked for field writes
  - `__index` which is invoked for field reads (including method lookup!)
- `REGISTRY["player-methods"]`, which holds all the instance methods

  - `__index` looks here for method implementations

As noted above, I've kept the table of metamethods and the table of methods separate in the hopes of minimizing conceptual confusion; idiomatic code would probably store all the methods and metamethods together, and use `luaL_getmetafield()` at the start of `playerset()` and `playerget()` to do method lookup.

Comment: Wow! Super detailed explanation. Absolutely wonderful. I have the v5.2 manual and sadly it kind of glosses over this concept.

Comment: The Manual is more of a reference work than anything else, so it describes all the parts and what they do in detail but it's largely up to you to figure out how to put them together effectively. I believe the lua-users wiki and the book "Programming in Lua" generally take a more "this is how you put the parts together to accomplish useful tasks" approach, but it's been a while since I looked at them.